# Page_link change

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

I'm trying to change default pages post type permalink, I'd like to add a '.php' to its end for example: `home_url() . post_name . '.php'`

I can't use WordPress permalinks page because I'm using it already like this: `/%category%/%postname%.php` and this doesn't affect the default pages post type.

**So I did it like follows:**

```
function wp_pages_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( empty( $post ) ) return $permalink;

    return home_url( $post->post_name . '.php'  );
}

add_filter( 'page_link', 'wp_pages_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

However I get a 404 when I try to visit the page, **and I have already flushed the rewrite rules by visiting the permalinks page**.

Comment: the page link filter affects output of permalinks, but it doesn't generate any rewrite rules for incoming requests. you'll have to add your own rewrite rules to handle the requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Milo. I'm poor at this, could you give me a little hint, an example maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, this needed a rewrite rule.. I don't know why post_link filter didn't need a rewrite rule added..

```
function ba_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)?.php', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'ba_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Posts didnt need a rewrite rule because setting the permalink structure on the settings page generates the rules for posts, there is no such setting for page post type.